# Why does this powershell script make two web requests (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)?

Tags: powershell, httpwebrequest

According to my server logs, the following script seems to make two web requests instead of one. Every single time the second request is exactly 2 minutes later. I only want one request. What am I missing?

```
# create the web request
$request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($url)
# set the timeout to 1 hour
$request.Timeout = 3600000

# get the response and stream
Write-Host "GetResponse() start"
$response = $request.GetResponse()
Write-Host "GetResponse() done"

Write-Host "GetResponseStream() start"
$stream = $response.GetResponseStream()
Write-Host "GetResponseStream() end"

# read the stream
Write-Host "Read stream start"
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($stream)
$html = $reader.ReadToEnd()
Write-Host "Read stream end"

# output the html response
Write-Host $html

# clean up resources
$reader.Close()
$stream.Close()
$response.Close()

Write-Host "Done"
```

Comment: How long does this script take to execute?

Comment: To avoid timeout issues in the requested web page, I used the ThreadPool to start a new thread to take care of the time intensive stuff. The ps script now runs very fast and only makes one web request. I'm still curious though.

Comment: is your server issuing a redirect (301,302) response on the first webrequest? That would explain the two requests that you are seeing.

Comment: There are no redirects in the request. Its almost as if the request times out and then retries the operation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not à response, but an element of help.

I copy/past your PowerShell code in PowerGuy, and just initialyse $url with "".
Then I start WireShark (an open source sniffer) on my computer. You will find, here under the capture.

[image]

It shows only one answer/response. I suppress the other frames, but I receive "Heartbeat" from Google, nothing else and I wait for more than 2 minutes.

Once again, it's not an answer, but an element of response. You perhaps have to try to start your script from a virtual machine, in which you install WireShark.

I can make more tests, if you give me the URL of your server, the server type and technologie.

I hope it helps.

JP

Comment: Thanks for the information. The server URL isn't public but thanks for offering to test it. When I have a chance I'll try again with WireShark.